# How to extract first letters from different words in a string in c#

Tags: c#, string, extract, letter

I want to extract first letter of each word in a string. I have done a lot of googling and still without any aid. 

For example,`string text = "I Hate Programming";`

The desired answer should be like:

```
IHP
```

I know you guys are very good, I'm just new. thanks.

Comment: Define the `word`. Are these single words `aaa-bbbb` , `aaa's` , `aaa_bbb` , `aaa@bbb`?

Comment: @I4V in his example string, you can see that he is defining a word as a individual element in an array split by spaces.

Comment: @ChristianStewart What about `I Hate Programming.I hate c#`? Is `Programming.I` a single word?

Comment: @I4V Yes, considering there is no space there :) I cite the english language.

Comment: We are not here to work for you, we are here to help you. If you want to learn, prove it showing what you already tried. Flagging this question for close

Answer (score 7):

If you know that your delimiter is a space, you can do the following.

```
string text = "my text here";
string firstLetters = "";

foreach(var part in text.split(' ')){
    firstLetters += part.substring(0,1);
}
```

Basically you split your string by the space character, and grab the first letter using substring of each word.

Comment: Slow because string concatenation is horrible.

Comment: Indeed it is, but it's the most simple way to show it.

Comment: Given the fact that the OP is a beginner, a clear, easy to understand snippet trumps performance considerations.

Comment: I had the code for my earlier question. I will post the code. Thanks for ur concern.

Answer (score 3):

With a little bit of LINQ:

```
string text = "I Hate Programming";
string firstLetters = 
    String.Join(String.Empty, text.Split(new[] {' '}).Select(word => word.First()))
```

If you want to include characters likes - and ' as the start of words, just add them to the list of characters in the call to Split().

Comment: Again, he needs to know how the theory of this works - not how to do it in some nice code. Linq is great for seasoned programmers who want to shortcut code to write quicker, but for a beginner you **need to show them the theories behind the code** in the most simple way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Dont Hate Programming :D"
var firstLetters = new String(str.Split(' ').Select(x => x[0]).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(firstLetters); // DHP:
```

Comment: Linq is very nice, and I could have written that as well, but it could be confusing to someone who **needs to know how this works** not just a good way of doing it.

Comment: How it works? It works as he described it. He understands the logic. The logic is simple. He needed help with the code. Either way, you could avoid string concatenation even without Linq.

Comment: False, he has no idea how the logic works. "I want to extract first letter of each word in a string. I have done a lot of googling and still without any aid." - he doesn't know HOW to do it, he wants to do it, but obviously it's better to show them HOW to... If he did know how to do it, why would he be asking?

Comment: Anyway, he now has all the answers he's gonna need. No need to fight. Now he both understands and has a good way of doing it.

Comment: `he now has all the answers he's gonna need` If the word separator char is only *space*.

Comment: -1 for the lack of explanations

Comment: @fotanus You may not like the answer. but if it is not wrong or misleading,  it may be possible that some people can get benefit of it. So downvoting is harsh. I think i can find many answers/questions to downvote if I look to your profile.