# How to grab letters from a word multiple times with C#/LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, loops, active-directory, automation

So I am currently trying to create a AD automation program for the company I work for but I'm running into problems with names. First off I am grabbing their first name and last initial for their email, but I don't know how to grab another digit if that account already exists.

Ex.  JohnS@contoso.com    already exists and another gentleman with the same name works for us so I need to create.
Ex. JohnSm@contoso.com

I was trying to use this example but it didn't quite work out.
[How to extract first letters from different words in a string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368182/how-to-extract-first-letters-from-different-words-in-a-string-in-c-sharp)

I am looping this part of the program to check for an already created user if it's there then it will add another letter so on and so forth until the user is created. TY for the help!

Edit: Sorry English is not my first language.

My source code right now for this little part that is giving me a headache lol.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<utable> theList = new List<utable>();
        using (var context = new miEntities())
        {
            theList = context.utables.Where(o => o.Date == null && o.Department == "IS").ToList();

        }
        foreach (utable id in theList)
        {

            string Fname = id.Fname;
            string Lname = id.lname;
            var username = theList.Select((u, i) => new { u.lname, u.Fname, Len = theList.Take(i - 1).Count(iu => iu.Fname == u.Fname && iu.lname == u.lname) + 1 }).Select(u => u.Fname + u.lname.Substring(0, Math.Min(u.Len, u.lname.Length)) + (u.Len >= u.lname.Length ? (u.Len - u.lname.Length + 1).ToString() : ""));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", username));
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

I have the Console push right now just so I can see what it's pulling but I'm pulling nothing even though my requirements in the Database are there. Trying to use some of the code you guys have listed already.

Comment: Can you add something about why it isn't working out, what you are getting instead, or what troubleshooting you have already tried? It also would be helpful to include the snippet of your code that is not doing what you expect.

Comment: Can you show us examples of how the data will look?  Is it regulated (i.e consistently delimited)?  What does your current code look like?

Comment: I put my code up, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Well a 2 minute answer would be something like this:

```
    class User
    {
        public string FName, LName;
        public User(string fname, string lname) { FName = fname; LName = lname; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lst = new[] { new User("John", "Smith"), new User("Will", "Smith"), new User("John", "Smith") };
        var usernames = lst.Select((u, i) => u.FName + u.LName.Substring(0, lst.Take(i - 1).Count(iu => iu.FName == u.FName && iu.LName == u.LName) + 1));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", usernames));
    }
```

This gives the following output:

```
JohnS WillS JohnSm
```

The only interesting line is the assignment to `usernames`, a one liner Linq statement that for each element it counts how many *previous* elements (based on the current index) share both first and last names with the current one, and takes (`Take<>()`) that amount of characters (+1 so you always have at least one) out of the last name and appends it to the first name.

This obviously only works as long as you have enough characters in the last name, otherwise it will throw an exception. The easy fix is to start appending numbers -- simply append the count minus the number of characters in the name as a string. Call it homework!

Edit: Got bored, here's the version that appends the numbers also:

```
        var usernames = lst.Select((u, i) => new { u.LName, u.FName, Len = lst.Take(i - 1).Count(iu => iu.FName == u.FName && iu.LName == u.LName) + 1 })
            .Select(u => u.FName + u.LName.Substring(0, Math.Min(u.Len, u.LName.Length)) + (u.Len >= u.LName.Length ? (u.Len - u.LName.Length + 1).ToString() : ""));
```

Comment: I posted the source code if you don't mind taking a look at it. I tried to use your last bit, but I'm getting nothing in return. I might be using it wrong.

Comment: Why is it inside the for loop? It's an iterator over the entire list already.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.  I don't think you will have an issue with running out of letters in the last name because the order by should place the person with the shorter last  name first.

```
List<string[]> names = new List<string[]>()
{
    new string[] { "Jason", "Boyd" },
    new string[] { "Jason", "Boyle"},
    new string[] { "Jason", "Bower"},
    new string[] { "John", "Smith" },
    new string[] { "Will", "Smith"},
    new string[] { "John", "Smith"}
};

names
.OrderBy(x => x[0])
.ThenBy(x => x[1])
.Aggregate(new List<string>(), (acc, x) => 
{
    // Append first name.
    string temp = x[0];

    // Append the first character of the last name.
    temp += x[1][0];

    // If the accumulator has no names yet then add 'temp' and move on.
    if(acc.Count == 0)
    {
        acc.Add(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        // If the accumulator has names then construct a new name
        // by adding characters from the last name to 'temp' until
        // 'temp' does not match the last name in the accumulator.
        string lastEntry = acc.Last();
        int index = 1;
        while(lastEntry.IndexOf(temp, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            temp += x[1][index];
            index++;
        }

        // Add 'temp' to the accumulator.
        acc.Add(temp);
    }

    return acc;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> GenerateEmails()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < LastName.Length; i++)
        {
            yield return String.Format("{0}{1}@domain.com", FirstName, LastName.Substring(0, i+1));
        }
    }
}
```

The `GenerateEmails` Method gives you *email candidates*, that you can use to compare against a list of *registered users*, as follows:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        User user = CreateUser("jhon", "smik");
        Console.WriteLine(user.Email);
    }

    static User CreateUser(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        User user = new User { FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName };
        var registeredUsers = GetSampleUsers();

        foreach (string email in user.GenerateEmails())
        {
            if (!registeredUsers.Any(u => u.Email.Equals(email)))
            {
                user.Email = email;
                break;
            }
        }
        return user;
    }

    static List<User> GetSampleUsers()
    {
        return new List<User>
        {
            new User { FirstName = "jhon", LastName = "smith", Email = "jhon@domain.com" },
            new User { FirstName = "jhon", LastName = "sack", Email = "jhons@domain.com" },
            new User { FirstName = "jhon", LastName = "samuelson", Email = "jhonsa@domain.com" }
        };
    }

}
```

The `CreateUser` method creates a new `User` object and tries to initialize its `Email` property with a *unique email*.